# Twin Paradox and experience of speed

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I'm sure someone has thought and discussed this before - I just can't seem to find any answers. Maybe the answer is so simple no one bothers to write it anywhere...

The classical twin paradox:
Person A stays at Earth.
Person B hops on a spaceship, travels around 0.8c to a star 10 ly away. Then B turns around and returns to Earth.

A sees 23 years passing. B sees 11.5 years passing.

So far so good. Except that I can't get my head around how B sees travelling 20 ly in 11.5 years, seeing spaceship going over lightspeed (~1.7 c).

What am I missing here?

Comment: From where did you get the 1.7 $c$ ?

Comment: Length contraction. This is covered in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox#Travellers'_perspective) article.

Comment: @kaylimekay Thanks! I knew I had missed something.

Comment: B doesn't see that. B sees that he has gone to a point, that was 20 ly away before he started, in 11.5 years. But how far does that distance actually look to him while he's moving, because of length contraction?

Comment: Draw a spacetime diagram from the POV of A (forget about the Earth, it is just in the way), there is a lot more going on (that you can check directly) than you indicate in your question.  That is what you are missing!  Also make sure you understand what "see" really means in this context.

Answer (score 1):

See if this answers your question in a bit more detail.
The star is 10 ly away in A's frame. Due to length contraction, at $v= 0.8c$ the distance to the star in B's frame is  10 ly $\times\sqrt{1-v^2}$ = $0.6\times10$ ly = 6 ly.
B is traveling at $0.8c$ relative to A. And so is also traveling at $0.8c$ with respect to the star. B completes the trip in $\frac{2 \times 6~\mathrm{ly}}{0.8~\mathrm{ly/yr}} = 15$ years on his clock.
Meanwhile, in A's frame, the star is 10 ly away, so A sees the trip take $\frac{2 \times 10~\mathrm{ly}}{0.8~\mathrm{ly/yr} }=25$ years.
At the end of the the trip the ratio of B's clock to A's clock is $15/25 = 0.6$. Their age ratio is the same. This is the correct answer, and didn't need accelerations, changes in frames, etc.

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve legibility. I did it for you this time.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. Can I paste in text and equations from Mathcad? I'm familiar with that program. I see I did use the notion of Frames, but just for two that are really just Lorentz transform. I should add there is no need for "Symmetry Breaking". These frames are never symmetric, A's frame has a fixed Star. B's Frame has a moving star.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I looked at the reference, and can see I will never have time to learn this system. So could you answer my question on using Mathcad text?  Plus, since I'm new here, how would know if Lasse Z was satisfied with my explantion?

Comment: MathJax is the only formula setting system on this site. Mostly it’s quite straightforward, enclose expressions with dollar signs, ^ for superscript, backslash for special functions like \cos, etc. the original poster can select an answer if they choose but in my experience at least half never select one for whatever reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.  Not sure why someone would ask a question, then not follow up. My short answer is accurate,  but doesn't provide real insight for some people, who get hung up on acceleration, symmetry, frame switching, general relativity etc.